# How to get a user authentication token by allowing the user to fill in username and password from my site UI in .NET 4.0 using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api

I have created a Facebook application and have an application ID and application secret. Now I want to provide the user with a simple UI in which he/she will fill in the Facebook user name and password. On the proceed button click, how do get his/her authentication token?

So in future I will use the saved token to get particular user information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Take this Open ID](https://developers.google.com/accounts/)

[Check the Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10371809/1557322)  this will help you.

The procedure for token set you need to store it via local cookie over client's browser.

That's the step-by-step simple stuff to create this kind of application

Hope this will help you